# Windows Tesseract TESSDATA_PREFIX problem

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

i am making a OCR program with Tesseract, however it throws an exception as:

```
    Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
```

My tessdata folder and traineddata files are inside my root project folder, here is a reading part of my program:

```
public class textRecognizer {

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String mrzText;
    static String tesseractData = "/TextRecog/tessdata";
    static Tesseract tesObj = new Tesseract();

    static {
        tesObj.setDatapath(tesseractData);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        float startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        try {
            mrzText = tesObj.doOCR(new File("textimage.png"));
            System.out.println("Text in file is: "+mrzText);
        }
        
        catch(TesseractException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Time taken by program is: "+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    }
    
}
```

textimage.png is also in the project folder.

I tried:

Running `C:\Users\Ege\eclipse-workspace\TextRecog>set TESSDATA_PREFIX = C:\Users\Ege\eclipse-workspace\TextRecog\tessdata` in cmd.

Redownloading tesseract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the problem is directory of tesseractData string. Changed it to

```
static String tesseractData = "tessdata";
```

tessdata folder is in my project folder so there is no need to write full directory to that. Program is working fine now